# EJB entity manager flush not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I have the following bean method

```
A(){
    em.merge(object);
    em.flush();
    //some code
    B()
}

B(){
    //want to use here updated object which is fetched from database by its primary key
}
```

But here I am getting old object and not updated. I tried many ways which are suggested on stack overflow still I am not getting updated object.

Comment: I wonder what the JPA providers log says ...

Comment: Can you write a code in B(), how you are fetching the object. Also you can use the object returned by merge(). Object o=em.merge(object)

Comment: It's a EJB? Post your bean as minimal example.

Comment: Actually in B() I have published message which sends the primary key to consumer(ActivMQ) and in consumer I am fetching data with that primary key. When I add thread.sleep for 2/3 seconds then it works fine. Just to minimize the complexity for readers I havent written this details in my question